# Simple Trigonometry and algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, polynomials

If $$\sec\theta = X + \frac{1}{4X},$$ 
then what is $${\sec\theta + \tan\theta}$$  in terms of  $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \sec\theta=X+\frac1{4X}$

$\displaystyle\implies\tan^2\theta= \sec^2\theta-1=\left(X+\frac1{4X}\right)^2-1=\left(X+\frac1{4X}\right)^2-4\cdot X\cdot\frac1{4X}=\left(X-\frac1{4X}\right)^2$

$\displaystyle\implies\tan\theta=\pm\left(X-\frac1{4X}\right)$

---

Let $\displaystyle \sec\theta+\tan\theta= y\iff \sec\theta-\tan\theta=\frac1y$

$\displaystyle\implies 2\sec\theta=y+\frac1y$

$\displaystyle\implies y+\frac1y=2\sec\theta=2\left(X+\frac1{4X}\right)$

Rearrange to form a Quadratic Equation in $y$ and solve

Comment: that $\tan^2\theta$ on line three should just be $\tan\theta$

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, thanks for your observation on the typo

Comment: How secθ−tanθ= 1/y ??

Comment: @Sudhanshu, $$1=\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta=(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

Change $sec\theta$ to $\frac{1}{cos\theta}$ and solve for $cos\theta$.  Then, use the Pythagorean Identity ($sin^2\theta + cos^2\theta = 1$) to solve for $sin\theta$.  You know that $tan\theta = \frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta}$, so you I'll let you take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If     secθ=X+(1/(4X)),You can find  (secθ+tanθ).

Since  $sin^2  θ+ cos^2  θ  = 1$
 you can find  tanθ , Because $1-sec^2 θ= tan^2 θ$. 
So after finding $tan^2 θ$ ,get the square root of it. After that game is over . Find what u want.

Comment: In fact, $$\tan^2\theta= \sec^2\theta-1$$ not the one in the answer